# unexpected identifier Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element

Tags: php, mysql, database, request

I'm trying to debug my website bug i got this problem :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'oeuvre'. Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element.

This is the part of code :

```
<?php

$id_site = $_GET['id_site'];
include("include/heritage.php");

$num_vague = $_GET['num_vague'];


$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site = $_GET[id_site]");
while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
{
  $id_site = $donnees['id_site'];
  $id_client_site = $donnees['id_client_site'];
  $id_restaurateur_site = $donnees['id_restaurateur_site'];
  $nom_site = $donnees['nom_site'];
  $nom_site = str_replace("\"", "'", $nom_site);
  $cp_site = $donnees['cp_site'];
  $ville_site = $donnees['ville_site'];
  $adresse_site = $donnees['adresse_site'];

  $i2c_site = $donnees['i2c_site'];
}
```

This is the included file `heritage.php`:

```
<?php

$id_site = $_GET['id_site'];
$req_client = $bdd->query("SELECT nom_client FROM membre WHERE id_membre=" . $_SESSION['id_membre_login']);
$donnees_client = $req_client->fetch();
$client_name = $donnees_client['nom_client'];

if ($client_name != '') {
    $client_name = addslashes($client_name);
    $req_client = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE societe_client = '$client_name'");
    $donnees_client = $req_client->fetch();
    $passage_1_client = $donnees_client['passage_1_client'];
    $passage_2_client = $donnees_client['passage_2_client'];

    $couleur1 = $donnees_client['couleur1'];
    $couleur2 = $donnees_client['couleur2'];
    $couleur3 = $donnees_client['couleur3'];
}
if (isset($_GET['id_site'])) {
    $reqClientPassage = $bdd->query("
SELECT client.passage_1_client, client.passage_2_client
FROM site
INNER JOIN client ON client.id_client = site.id_client_site
WHERE id_site =" . $id_site
    );

    $donneesClientPassage = $reqClientPassage->fetch();

    $passage_1_client = $donneesClientPassage['passage_1_client'];
    $passage_2_client = $donneesClientPassage['passage_2_client'];
}
?>
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: check for "oeuvre" this string in the included files and their might be a syntax error in those files. shared code seems to be fine.

Comment: put your output on editing question

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site =". $_GET['id_site']); //single quote missing
```

Comment: @EythanFellous 'oeuvre' this string coming from where? `print_r($donnees);exit;` do this and share the output here

Comment: This the result : Array ( [id_site] => 1600 [0] => 1600 [id_client_site] => 52 [1] => 52 [id_client_interlocuteur] => 0 [2] => 0 [id_restaurateur_site] => 41 [3] => 41 [id_restaurateur_interlocuteur] => [4] => [nom_site] => Gestion privée [5] => Gestion privée [adresse_site] => [6] => [cp_site] => [7] => [ville_site] => [8] => [region_site] => vide [9] => vide [i_self_site] => [10] => [i_cafeterie_site] => [11] => [i_rapide_site] => [12] => [i_da_site] => [13] => [i_room_site] => [14] => [i_club_site] => [15] => [i_traiteur_site] => [16] => [id_secteur1_client_site] => [17] =>

Comment: [id_secteur2_client_site] => [18] => [id_secteur1_restaurateur_site] => [19] => [id_secteur2_restaurateur_site] => [20] => [ref_contrat_site] => [21] => [date_debut_contrat] => [22] => [date_fin_contrat] => [23] => [date_fin_vague] => 2018-01-01 [24] => 2018-01-01 [nb_vague_annee] => [25] => [extfichier_contrat] => [26] => [publication] => ok [27] => ok [id_auditeur] => [28] => [i2c_site] => [29] => [i2c_date_site] => [30] => [nb_vague_site] => [31] => [id_secteur3_client_site] => [32] => [id_secteur4_client_site] => [33] => [id_secteur5_client_site] => [34] =>

Comment: => [id_secteur3_restaurateur_site] => [35] => [id_secteur4_restaurateur_site] => [36] => [id_secteur5_restaurateur_site] => [37] => [commentaire] => [38] => )

Comment: 'oeuvre' this word coming from where? check

Comment: i didn't find 'oeuvre' :/

Answer (score 1):

Change below line,

```
$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site = $_GET[id_site]");
```

to

```
$id = $_GET['id_site'];
$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site = $id");
```

Your syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

remove `$_GET[id_site]` from below query and add this `$id_site` variable

`$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site = $_GET[id_site]");`

To

`$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site = $id_site");`

Comment: what you have done in this line `$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM site where id_site = $_GET[id_site]");`